# How to adjust mouse click debounce

Tags: xorg, mouse

How do you adjust the mouse click debouncing in Ubuntu?

I recently bought an IOGear wireless keyboard, and while most functions appear to work "out-of-the-box", the builtin mouse keys seem to have no debouncing, so a single click usually registers as multiple clicks. This renders the mouse functionality incredibly frustrating, if not outright unusable.

I tried the "Mouse settings" dialog, but all it has is a slider to increase the allowable time between clicks in a double click, which is the exact opposite of what I want. e.g. it allows me to wait several seconds between clicks, and still have it register as a "double click".

I'm looking for some what to say, "if you detect two or more mouse clicks within 100ms, then ignore all but the first". How would I specify that? I feel there might be some way to do this in xorg.conf but I'm having trouble finding any documentation.

Comment: similar problem (and more solutions) can be found at http://askubuntu.com/questions/321816/mouse-sometimes-doubleclicks-when-i-click-once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find an xorg setting, but I discovered there's actually a "rapid-fire" setting on the keyboard itself that was causing this. Turning that off fixed the problem.